# Go: accept different socket calls in one function

Tags: sockets, go

I'm trying to get my web server to accept different socket calls in one function. My code looks like this:

Go:

```
func handler(w io.Writer, r *io.ReadCloser) {
    //do something
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

I get the error:

```
cannot use handler (type func(io.Writer, *io.ReadCloser)) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to http.HandleFunc
```

How do I implement this?

Comment: That's not the signature for an http handler. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the article "[Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_3)", the example for HandleFunc is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

You cannot replace a `r *http.Request` by an `r *io.ReadCloser`.

You would need to delegate that call in a wrapper, as suggested [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/khlko0elzag):

```
func wrappingHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    handler(w, r.Body)
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", wrappingHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Or simply modify your handler:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rb := r.Body
    //do something with rb instead of r
}
```